# Access data from azure cold storage through SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, ssms, azure-storage

So for my Azure cloud-hosted application, I am using two databases, **primary** and **secondary**, respectively. The old data in the primary db is set up to be moved to the secondary db after it is not needed anymore. As a result, the secondary db with the bulk amount of data over a period of time takes a long enough time to be accessed through the SQL queries which is undesired.

So I have stored the secondary db's older data in azure cold storage and now I am trying to figure out a way to access it through **SQL** queries from the cold storage itself. But even though, through **SSMS**, connection to Azure cold storage is **possible**, I am **not** getting any option to run SQL queries since ***I am connected to Azure storage account, not a database engine.***

Is there any solution to this? Or ANY workaround?

My aim is to **store** that unnecessary secondary db data in the **Azure cold storage** and **access it from there through SQL queries** whenever needed.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option would be, rather than using cold storage, look at putting the archive data in an archive schema. Look at stretching your DB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/stretch-database/stretch-database?view=sql-server-ver15 - stretching works in a similar vein to cold storage, but allows SQL queries to work normally

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll implement and see how it goes